# define a new column

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to define a column which is 1 for rows with `col3==loop` it is 2 after `col3==loop` until they get to a row with `col3==loop` or `col3==a` or `col3==b.` otherwise 0.

example

```
        group1    group2     col3
          1         1         a
          1         1         loop
          1         1         d
          1         1         c
          1         1         b
          1         1         f
          1         2         loop
          1         2         a
          1         2         loop
          1         2          f
          2         1         loop
          2         1          g

        group1    group2     col3          loop
          1         1         a             0
          1         1         loop          1
          1         1         d             2
          1         1         c             2 
          1         1         b             2
          1         1         f             0
          1         2         loop          1
          1         2         a             2
          1         2         h             0
          1         2          f            0
          2         1          b            0
          2         1          g            0
```

let me know if it is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does what the question asks for. It uses index vectors to assign `1` and `2` to the appropriate places in the new column. I have read in the expected output and created column `loop2` to compare the result with the posted column `loop`. Change this after checking if the answer is right.

```
i1 <- which(df1$col3 == "loop")
i2 <- which(df1$col3 %in% c("a", "b"))
df1$loop2 <- 0
df1$loop2[i1] <- 1
k <- Map(`:`, (i1 + 1), i2[findInterval(i1, i2) + 1])
df1$loop2[unlist(k)] <- 2

df1
#   group1 group2 col3 loop loop2
#1       1      1    a    0     0
#2       1      1 loop    1     1
#3       1      1    d    2     2
#4       1      1    c    2     2
#5       1      1    b    2     2
#6       1      1    f    0     0
#7       1      2 loop    1     1
#8       1      2    a    2     2
#9       1      2    h    0     0
#10      1      2    f    0     0
#11      2      1    b    0     0
#12      2      1    g    0     0
```

**Data.**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
        group1    group2     col3          loop
          1         1         a             0
          1         1         loop          1
          1         1         d             2
          1         1         c             2 
          1         1         b             2
          1         1         f             0
          1         2         loop          1
          1         2         a             2
          1         2         h             0
          1         2          f            0
          2         1          b            0
          2         1          g            0
", header = TRUE)
```